# Multi-Foci Force Layout with ordinal scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

This layout has an ordinal scale: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919

```
     var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
         .domain(d3.range(m))
         .rangePoints([0, width], 1);
```

But, nothing changes when "x" is included in the data e.g.

```
     var nodes = [
        { "radius": 50, "color": "#17becf", "cx": 800, "cy": 250, "x": 100},
        { "radius": 50, "color": "#17becf", "cx": 800, "cy": 250, "x": 200},
        { "radius": 50, "color": "#17becf", "cx": 800, "cy": 250, "x": 300},
        { "radius": 50, "color": "#17becf", "cx": 800, "cy": 250, "x": 400},];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to explain this a bit more. Where is your code breaking down? Note, in Mike's example, that you have it's the `gravity()` function which moves the nodes to their respective clusters.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt Mike's code so that the ordinal scale moves the nodes to their respective clusters?

Comment: [No.](http://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) Ordinal scales don't "move" things, necessarily; it's the `gravity()` function which does that in a force layout. [Read this](http://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_in_d3.html) - it's a very helpful tutorial, explains the components of gravity functions.

Comment: So is it not possible to fix the x-position and let the force layout take care of the y-position?

Comment: No, not as such -- you can set the position to be fixed, but that means that both coordinates are. The only way to achieve what you want is to reset the x position of the nodes in the tick handler to create the illusion that it is fixed.

Comment: Like this? function tick(e) {
  circle
      .each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
      .each(collide(.5))
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}